# How add in schema a List of object(child) optional Javascript(React-Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, realm

Thank you very much in advance.
I am developing a quiz application that has two types of answer forms
 one with multiple choice **options**
 and another open question **input**, then in the realm schema I made the following configuration

#### Option schema(optional)

```js
const OptionSchema = {
  name: 'Option',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: {type: 'int', indexed: true},
    description: 'string?',
    imageSound: 'string?',
    correct: 'bool',
    marked: 'bool?',
    play: 'bool?',
  },
};

export default OptionSchema;
```

#### Question Schema

```js
const QuestionSchema = {
  name: 'Question',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: {type: 'int', indexed: true},
    questionForm: 'string',
    optionForm: 'string',
    typeAnswer: 'string',
    description: 'string',
    correctAnswerDescription: 'string?',
    correctAnswerDescriptionId: 'string?',
    imageSound: 'string?',
    options: 'Option?[]',
  },
};
export default QuestionSchema;
```

#### The Question

I was wondering how do I leave the options
`property: 'Option []'`
optiocinal in schema because it is not getting
reading the documentation there are the following cases:
**for properties**

```js
displayName: 'string?', // optional property
birthday:    {type: 'date', optional: true}, // optional property
```

**for list**

```js
testScores: 'double?[]'
```

#### Attempts

trying both ways in my case
**first try**

```js
options:    {type: 'Option[]', optional: true},
```

**second try**

```js
options:'Option?[]'
```

in neither case did it work
would you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option that does not solve the problem but may help temporarily would be:

add a null record and all registration that is not registered you point null as a child.
example

### Schema Option

```js
const OptionSchema = {
  name: 'Option',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: {type: 'int', indexed: true, optional: true},
    description: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    imageSound: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    correct: {type: 'bool', optional: true},
    marked: {type: 'bool', optional: true},
    play: {type: 'bool', optional: true},
  },
};

export default OptionSchema;
```

### Schema Question

```js
const QuestionSchema = {
  name: 'Question',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: {type: 'int', indexed: true},
    questionForm: 'string',
    optionForm: 'string',
    typeAnswer: 'string',
    description: 'string',
    correctAnswerDescription: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    correctAnswerDescriptionId: {type: 'int', optional: true},
    imageSound: {type: 'string', optional: true},
    options: 'Option[]',
  },
};
export default QuestionSchema;
```

### Images - Schema Option(children)

[image]

### Images - Schema Question(father)

[image]

thank you all I hope I helped until the problem has a solution.